# pasar a jquery correctamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo que transformar de javascript vanilla a jquery un código y tengo esto en javascript vanilla:

```
const element = list[i];
element.innerHTML = '';
```

Si lo quiero transformar a jquery sería `element.text('');` ? Por alguna razón no me funciona, así que no se si estoy haciéndolo correctamente, gracias!

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no es lo mismo innerText que innerHTML. Si bien ambos poseen funciones GET y SET los valores devueltos por cada uno son distintos. Te recomiendo este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery no provee ningún `Object.prototype.text`, debes hacerlo con el método que ofrece, ya sea `$` o `jQuery`

```javascript
jQuery(element).html('');
```

El equivalente de `innerHTML` es `.html()` en jQuery, si usas `.text()` solo se cambiará `innerText`, esto omitirá el HTML que se le intente añadir

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! el fallo era que yo no añadía jquery ni lo colocaba en un paréntesis, se colocaría en el paréntesis al ser una variable (element)?

Comment: jQuery no solo recibe strings, también puede recibir objetos que contengan el elemento HTML y lo puede cambiar de igual manera

Comment: Muchas gracias! comprendo